# "Good subjective, bad subjective" notice

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that the "Good subjective, bad subjective" notice appears to be attached to [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2401/869). I'm unable to find any other examples of it across the Stack Exchange network currently, but I had thought the notice is typically attached to questions. Is that the case, and The Workplace is deviating from the standard? If so, why?

Comment: i'm confused, is this something that only mods/original poster can see?

Comment: It appears the answer has been deleted, so now only mods and high-rep users (usually 10k, not sure what the threshold is for a beta site) can see the answer. The notice, though, is visible to all.

Comment: (visible to all when it is attached to a post that is not deleted)

Comment: ahh.  Ok then.  thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The post notice options/comments are the same for Answers and Questions:

[image]

The reason you usually see Insufficient Explanation on questions rather than answers is to try and keep a thread, rather than a specific answer, focused and good-subjective.

In this case the question didn't appear to be attracting multiple bad-subjective answers, just the one. In addition, adding the post notice to the answer generates a notification (I think) to the answerer, making it actionable. Those last two reasons are why I post the notice on that answer. At least I think it was me.

As a side note, if you see a question or answer in need of one of these notices, **flag it** with an "Other" flag and explain which post notice the post needs and why. If your post has gotten a post notice and you feel you've resolved the problem with the post, flag it and a moderator can review and potentially remove the post notice.

---

Going through Review/low quality posts I converted  this answer to a comment. The entire content was:

> Yes. You lose nothing by asking for details.

Comment: +1 for using another tool in the toolbox to help encourage great answers.